# How to lead a shot at a target undergoing uniform circular motion

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, roots, projectile-motion

I'm playing [a programming game](https://jsbattle.jmrlab.com/) in which script-controlled tanks drive around and try to shoot each other until only one side remains. Because of the way the steering works, the tanks often follow circular trajectories, so leading a shot in those circumstances is very useful.

I have developed an equation that seems to find a correct shot angle, but I can only solve it numerically. I was hoping that someone here could help me come up with a closed-form solution, or propose a different way of approaching the problem that might be better all around. Here's how my solution works:

Concept: If I fire at time 0, then the bullet can only hit if at some time $t$, the enemy and the bullet are equidistant from me. If I can find the value for $t$, then I can determine where the enemy will be at that time and from there I can compute the angle I should use for aiming.

In order to compute this, here's what I did:

- $\omega_0$ is the enemy's initial angle from the $x$ axis
- $\omega$ is the enemy's rate of turn, in radians per time

The enemy tank's velocity $\vec{v}(t)$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{v}(t) &= \left|\vec{v}_0\right| \left(\cos\left(\omega_0 + \omega t\right) \hat{\imath} + \sin\left(\omega_0 + \omega t\right) \hat{\jmath}\right)
\end{align}
$$

The tank's position $\vec{e}(t)$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{e}(t) &= \vec{e}_0 + |\vec{v}_0|\int_0^t \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\imath}\, dt  + |\vec{v}_0| \int_0^t \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\jmath}\, dt \\
&= \vec{e}_0 + {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\imath} -{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\jmath} \\
\end{align}
$$

The bullet's distance from me $b(t)$ is given by
$$
b(t) = Qt
$$

If my position is $\vec{p}$, then the tank's position *relative to my position* is $\vec{r}(t)$

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{r}(t) &= \vec{e}(t) - \vec{p}\\
&= \vec{e}_0 - \vec{p} + {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\imath} -{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\jmath}\\
&= \left(e_{0.x} - p_x + {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t)\right)\hat{\imath} 
+ \left(e_{0.y} - p_y - {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t)\right)\hat{\jmath}\\
\end{align}
$$

So, what I want is to find a $t$ such that (recall $Q$ is the bullet's speed)
$$
\begin{align}
|\vec{r}(t)| &= Qt \\[6pt]
\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}(t) &= Q^2 t^2\\
\left(e_{0.x} - p_x + {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t)\right)^2 
+ \left(e_{0.y} - p_y - {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t)\right)^2 &= Q^2 t^2\\
\end{align} 
$$

Let
$$
\begin{align}
A &= e_{0.x} - p_x\\
B &= e_{0.y} - p_y\\
\end{align}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(A + {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t)\right)^2 
+ \left(B - {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t)\right)^2 &= Q^2 t^2\\
A^2 + 2A{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t) + \left({|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega}\right)^2 \sin^2(\omega_0 + \omega t) \qquad & \\ 
\qquad {}+ B^2 - 2B{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t) + \left({|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega}\right)^2 \cos^2(\omega_0 + \omega t) &= Q^2 t^2 \\
\left({|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega}\right)^2 + A^2 + B^2 +2A{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega}\cos(\omega_0 + \omega t)  - 2B{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega}\sin(\omega_0 + \omega t) &= Q^2t^2
\end{align} 
$$

I was unable to solve this, so I had to evaluate it numerically using bisection. Based on that and my basic testing, this *seems* to yield correct results. This is good enough for tank combat, but I want to know if there is a way to write a general solution, or maybe if there is a better way to approach this problem altogether.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I don't think you can avoid numerical methods if you want an accurate solution, but you can get the answer by solving a simpler equation.

---

Let's consider just the distance from the point $\vec p$ from which you fired to the point $\vec e(t)$ where the tank is at time $t$.

Then in order for you to hit the tank at time $t$, $t$ needs to be a solution of the equation

$$
 \lVert \vec e(t) - \vec p \rVert = Qt. \tag1 \label{eq:hit} 
$$

(You also need to aim in the right direction, but let's leave that problem for later.)

Let $C$ be the center of the circle traveled by the tank,
with position vector $\vec c$. Let $E(t)$ and $P$ be the points described by the position vectors $\vec e(t)$ and $\vec p$.

Suppose that at the instant you fire, the points $E(t)$, $C$, and $P$ form a triangle with angle $\theta_0$ at vertex $E_0$ and that the angle is increasing at the rate $\omega$
as $E(t)$ moves around its circular path, so the angle at a time $t$ shortly after you fire is $\theta(t) = \theta_0 + \omega t$.

For convenience, let $R_0 = \lVert \vec e(t) - \vec c \rVert$ (which is constant)
and let $r_0 = \lVert \vec p - \vec c \rVert$.

Then the law of cosines says

$$ \lVert \vec e(t) - \vec p \rVert^2 = R_0^2 + r_0^2 - 2 R_0 r_0 \cos(\theta(t)). $$

Use Equation \eqref{eq:hit} to replace the left-hand side with $Qt$
and replace $\theta(t)$ as we defined it earlier:

$$ Qt = R_0^2 + r_0^2 - 2 R_0 r_0 \cos(\theta_0 + \omega t). \tag2 \label{eq:t}$$

The functions we usually consider elementary are not sufficient to solve equations like this. A numerical solution seems like your best bet.

But if you solve for $t$ in Equation \eqref{eq:t}, you know where the enemy tank will be at that time, so you can simply aim in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question! Your final result looks much simpler than mine, but I have to confess that I don't understand a couple of the steps (mostly regarding the construction of the triangle as it relates to t), so some work is required on my part.

Comment: Yes, this method is not quite as completely worked out as yours. There are various ways to measure an angle between vectors (I think you want the angle between $\vec e(t) - \vec e_0$ and $\vec p - \vec e_0$) and you need to be careful about which direction the initial angle faces. Rather than just an angle from $0$ to $\pi$ I think you want a signed angle from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ so that the angle $t$ seconds later is $\theta_0 + \omega t$ and not $\theta_0 - \omega t$.

Comment: I figured out what the source of my original confusion was (I misunderstood how you stated to lay the points into a triangle and measure the change over the entire time period, but I believe I follow you now). Later in the solution, I don't understand how  $R_0 = |\vec{e}(t) - \vec{e_0}|$ is a constant because of its apparent dependency on $t$. Are we able to do that because we know we're looking for a fixed solution at a single point?

Comment: I assumed $\vec e_0$ was the center of the circle based on the formula $\vec{e}_0 + {|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \sin(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\imath} -{|\vec{v}_0|\over \omega} \cos(\omega_0 + \omega t) \hat{\jmath}$. But I see that you set up the integral to use $\vec e_0$ as the tank's initial position. I think there's an error in the integration (off by a constant). I introduced my own names for the center of the circle to try to improve the answer. $R_0$ is simply the radius of the circle, the constant distance from $\vec e(t)$ to the center of the circle.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I will check over the integration and study your solution some more now that I understand where it's coming from. Thanks again for your help and patience, it's been 20+ years since I did anything like this.